# How to extend oracle database to a newly added hard disk

Tags: oracle

I'm a begineer to Oracle database admin role. Recently I have added a new hard drive to extend the capacity of an oracle database which runs on Linux. How to extend the oracle database to utilize new hard disk storage. Please explain the steps in point form.

Comment: I am not sure that adding a hard drive to an existing database is an appropriate task for a beginner to the db admin role. Why were **you** given this task, and not someone more experienced? In any case, I flagged your question for "closing" (really, for moving it to the DBA StackExchange forum, which is a better place for your question).

Comment: It's a test server :)

Comment: You can use new hard disk to store data files of the existing tablespace. Do you want to use new hard deive for such purpose?

Comment: @Tejash Yes, Is that automatically do through ASM? or is there any configuration?

Comment: You must ask this question on dba stackexchange as it is complex task using ASM. You will definately get good answers by experts in that forum.

Comment: Might be a duplicate of [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33901/add-additional-disks-to-fra-diskgroup-in-asm/33904#33904)

Comment: It depends on how you use the disks presented to this host. Oracle ASM, Linux LVM, seperate mount points per disk, raw devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As beginner, I strongly recommend to start working with the classical way on filesystems.

Then you must be aware, where do you need more capacity within your database.

Ensure, that the new disk is available on OS. Then go ahead with following hints and steps:
(Very high level, simple and the classic way)

- Users can create objects (Tables, Indexes, Views, Procedures, Sequence, ...)
- Objects, which are storing any kind of data are segments, e.g. tables/indexes.
- Each table is always stored within only one Tablespace.
- Users can locate different tables/indexes etc. into different Tablespaces.
- Tablespaces consist of one or more datafiles.
- A DBA can add as many datafiles to a tablespace as he likes (ALTER TABLESPACE ADD DATAFILE).
- Each new datafile enlarges the capacity of only this tablespace.

To answer your question, you need to know, which tablespace needs the additional space. Then you can add a new datafile with command above (there are tons of examples) and locate the datafile to the mountpoint of your new disk.

If you are new, you should start with a database on standard filesystems and play around with datafiles. Other options like ASM are not a good starting point for beginners, if you want to learn.

Comment: Great explanation. Thanks @Lohrsträter

Comment: **NOTE** -  "Raw-devices" is no longer an option.